# AngularJS - Inject Factory into the run of the main module

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory defined as `app.factory('MyFactor')`, and I want to inject this into the `.run()` of my main module.

I tried the same way I inject dependencies into a directive:

```
app.run(['MyFactory', function(MyFactory)
{

}]);
```

But I get an error say that this is an unknown Provider. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Where is `MyFactory` created?

Comment: As a sidenote, if you declared it as `app.factory('MyFactor')` then that's your problem right there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Injecting instances into a `run` function works. There were two wrong answers to this question claiming it doesn't.

Consider this:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.factory('myFactory', function() {
    return {
        foo: function() { return 'bar' }
    };
})
.run(['myFactory', function(myFactory) {
    alert(myFactory.foo());
}]);
```

It runs without errors and alerts the result from invoking a function on the `myFactory` service
(yes it's still a service even if you call it a factory).

Most likely your error is caused by a misspelling of the name. In your posted code you have `app.factory('MyFactor')` which is missing a trailing "y".

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/os4erzjx/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But No, misspelling is not the issue. This was a typo here. But I think I figured out the problem. This was helpful

Comment: My problem with this is that I would like to exclude the factory in a separate file and that would mean a endless dependency loop

Comment: @julmot That shouldn't by itself create a dependency loop but you have to make sure the factory is registered with the module before you try to inject it. I've always kept my factories and services in separate files

Comment: How did you realized it with this example? I have a "main.js" file where I initialize the "app" module and where the .run-method lives. Then I have a factory that should be used inside the .run-method but is based on the "app" module that is not already registered. So I would need to create a third file with just the module creation inside?

Comment: @julmot Yes, basically.